# terragrunt cannot get directory name 2 levels above

Tags: terragrunt

I was looking at the documentation of dirname and basename functions of terragrunt and am very surprised that no one from stackoverflow ever asked this question

Documentation: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/dirname

I have the following path:

/rootdir/vpc-test/networking/vpc/terragrunt.hcl

I would like to use the vpc-test as the vpc name. How can I obtain this ?

I have tried ${basename(dirname(get_terragrunt_dir()))}", this is apparently the most used super variable in terragrunt but I get networking, not vpc-test

Please if you have any experience, tutorial it will really help me with this terragrunt mental torture

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is the following:

```
  current_dir = "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/../../"
  vpc_name = basename(dirname(local.current_dir))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**